# Show array json to SELECT any rows

Tags: php

I need to return an array in JSON format.

Format is not a problem.

The problem is to take the $row index and display it.

```
$db = new Connect;
$data = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM trabalhos_cientificos");

$data->execute();
$row = $data->fetch();
if( $row == null ){
    $users['message'] = "Sem assessorias.";
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode($users);
    exit();
}else{

 //$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data->fetch());
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data); //line 170
 foreach($row as $r) { //line 171
     $users[] = $r;
     echo json_encode($r['id_trabalhos_cientificos']);
 }
 echo json_encode(array('Data1' => $users));

 while(($row = mysqli_fetch_row($data))) { //line 177
      $users[] = $row;
      echo json_encode($row['id_trabalhos_cientificos']);
 }
 echo json_encode(array('Data2' => $users));

http_response_code(200);
//echo json_encode($users);
//echo json_encode(array($users));
exit();

}
```

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/.../logado.php on line 170

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/.../logado.php on line 171
{"Data1":[]}
Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in /opt/lampp/.../logado.php on line 177
{"Data2":[]}

[image]

Comment: seems like you wanted list of `id` in array and array should be wrapped by `{}`

Comment: You are fetching all over the place. It's extremely unclear what you're trying to do or what your desired results are.

Comment: @El_Vanja my needed results is an array with the select result, in json format

Comment: @sashiksu my needed results is an array with the select result, in json format

Comment: Then [`fetch_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all) and `json_encode`?

Comment: @El_Vanja fetch_all

Comment: @El_Vanja great,,, tks.... woks

Answer (score 0):

Solution... using **fetchAll()** and **foreach($row as $r)**

```
$data->execute();
$row = $data->fetchAll();
if( $row == null ){
    $users['message'] = "Sem assessorias.";
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode($users);
    exit();
}
else{
  foreach($row as $r){
      $users[] = array(
        'idTrabalhosCientificos' => $r['id_trabalhos_cientificos']
                      );
 }
}
```

TKs @El_Vanja

Tks all

Answer (score -1):

$data = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM trabalhos_cientificos");

here prepare() is a PDO Class function and mysqli_fetch_row() is mysqli

either use PDO class method for  fetching rows or use Mysqli connection

Comment: See first line of OP's code: `$db = new Connect;`, they have some sort of db wrapper.

Comment: By the way, `mysqli` has a `prepare` in [OOP form](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare).